# Temperature-Dependent Electrical resistance Si and SiC

Tags: power-electronics, semiconductors, materials, solid-state-devices, device-characteristics

In a power electronics device, it seems that silicon carbide (SiC) has a higher variation of electrical on-state resistance with temperature in comparison to silicon (Si). Does anybody know the reason? I googled it, but I did find nothing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that helped me (**Page 2 of 6 shows good comparisons**): https://www.fairchildsemi.co.jp/Assets/zSystem/documents-archive/collateral/technicalArticle/Overview-of-Silicon-Carbide-Power-Devices.pdf

**To summarize**:

- Higher band-gap energy variance
- Lower magnetic reluctance
- Higher thermal condcutivity
- Higher hole and electron mobility (more scattering is possible, meaning more variance)

Comment: Thank you for your comment,    in the link, it is mentioned: The ON-resistance of the SiC MOSFET increases by about 20 percent when the junction temperature increases from 25°C to 135°C, whereas that of the Si MOSFET increases by 250 percent......                While in datasheets you can find a contrary conclusion.

Comment: Of course, I am talking about Si IGBTs and SiC MOSFETs.